# Is there a version control system for random files not under a single directory?

Tags: version-control

I want to version control my linux scripts & settings. I have a list of the files & directories I care about, they're all over the file system. I don't want to track my home dir as there's many files I don't want to track & it contains symlinks to external locations. Is there a version control system which can track specified files in an location external to the version control's root directory?

**Update :** I found "git config core.worktree /" would track everything under /, though the file locations in the repo are forced to be the canonical paths excluding symlinks so it's not really suitable.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution is to keep the repo separate, and use an "install"-like system to deploy the updated files to their respective system locations.

Comment: I had a link to http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/ but I'm not sure how it works exactly, so I figure it makes more sense as a tangential comment.

Comment: But after the files have been installed, they're not tracked

Comment: Part of the regime is you're not supposed to edit the destination files directly. But e.g. `etckeeper` apparently has a facility to sync the repo from the live files.